# Add Items to Combobox only if they contain a string

Tags: c#, winforms

What I'm trying to achieve is adding an item to `comboBox24`, but only if a string is contained in `comboBox10`.

```
          case "PN63":
                    comboBox24.Items.Clear();
                    
                    if (comboBox10.Items.Contains("CL150"))
                    {
                        comboBox24.Items.Add("ASME B16.5-150 RF");
                    }
                    else if (comboBox10.Items.Contains("PN16"))
                    {
                        comboBox24.Items.Add("FLG EN1092-1 PN16 B1");
                    }
                    else if (comboBox10.Items.Contains("PN25"))
                    {
                        comboBox24.Items.Add("FLG EN1092-1 PN25 B1"); ;
                    }
                    else if (comboBox10.Items.Contains("PN40"))
                    {
                        comboBox24.Items.Add("FLG EN1092-1 PN40 B1");
                    }
                    else if (comboBox10.Items.Contains("CL300"))
                    {
                        comboBox24.Items.Add("ASME B16.5-300 RF");
                    }
                    break;
```

So far , I achieve adding only a single (first) item even when multiple conditions are true.
I'm not very experienced but I'm thinking the if statement breaks after `true`.

Can anyone please point me on how to achieve this.

Comment: Remove all the `else` keywords. Then all tests are done. Otherwise, it breaks after the first `true` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `case "PN63":` has me worried.  Do you have a ton of other cases that have basically the same type of code but with different values?

If so, I recommend you use something more like:

```
case "PN63":
    string[,] pairs = {
        {"CL150", "ASME B16.5-150 RF" },
        {"PN16", "FLG EN1092-1 PN16 B1" },
        {"PN25", "FLG EN1092-1 PN25 B1" },
        {"PN40", "FLG EN1092-1 PN40 B1" },
        {"CL300", "ASME B16.5-300 RF" }
    };
    SetComboboxes(comboBox10, comboBox24, pairs);
    break;
```

With the helper method `SetComboboxes()`:

```
private void SetComboboxes(ComboBox comboToCheck, ComboBox comboToAdd, string[,] pairs)
{
    comboToAdd.Items.Clear();
    for (int r = 0; r <= pairs.GetUpperBound(0); r++)
    {
        if (comboToCheck.Items.Contains(pairs[r, 0]))
        {
            comboToAdd.Items.Contains(pairs[r, 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are testing different conditions and want all of them to execute, so you should remove the else keyword and make them just if statements.

```
          case "PN63":
                comboBox24.Items.Clear();
                
                if (comboBox10.Items.Contains("CL150"))
                {
                    comboBox24.Items.Add("ASME B16.5-150 RF");
                }
                if (comboBox10.Items.Contains("PN16"))
                {
                    comboBox24.Items.Add("FLG EN1092-1 PN16 B1");
                }
                if (comboBox10.Items.Contains("PN25"))
                {
                    comboBox24.Items.Add("FLG EN1092-1 PN25 B1"); ;
                }
                if (comboBox10.Items.Contains("PN40"))
                {
                    comboBox24.Items.Add("FLG EN1092-1 PN40 B1");
                }
                if (comboBox10.Items.Contains("CL300"))
                {
                    comboBox24.Items.Add("ASME B16.5-300 RF");
                }
                break;
```